# C# program to find no of words that can be generated from a word by adding ' . ' in between characters?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, algorithm

I asked this question in the chat room. but no answer so i am posting the question here.

The question is, for example take the word abcd

it has 4 charcters. by adding the ' . ' in between the characters you can write it as a.b.c.d

**rules**
can use only 1 dot between characters
can use multiple dots in the word
*Edit:* there can be characters without ' . ' in between them. eg (ab or abcd)
cannot use dot at the beginning or end of the word ie .abcd or abcd. are false

some of the answers
a.b.c.d
a.bcd
ab.cd
abc.d
a.b.cd
a.bc.d
ab.c.d
abc.d

how many word are possible to make. how to write a program to find it in c# ?

**Edit**
how to display each possible word ?

Comment: Are we missing a homework tag here maybe? :)

Comment: If this is homework, please include the [Homework] tag.

Comment: its not a homework. i just got an idea. should i add homework tag

Comment: Did you want just the number or to calculate all the answers?

Comment: @paul: yes, you got me. i have edited the question. take a look.

Comment: @Vishnu, take a look at Guffa's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it recursively.

All possible combinations of (abcd) are:

```
a + . + all combinations of (bcd)
ab + . + all combinations of (cd)
abc + . + all combinations of (d)
abcd
```

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(string str) {
  for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++) {
    foreach (string s in GetCombinations(str.Substring(i))) {
      yield return str.Substring(0, i) + "." + s;
    }
  }
  yield return str;
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (string s in GetCombinations("abcd")) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't really need to write a program for this.

For a word of n characters, there are n-1 positions where there can be a dot (i.e. between each pair of characters). Each position either has a dot or doesn't.

There are therefore 2<sup>n-1</sup> possible words.

If you *really* want to write a C# program to display this:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Argument validation left as an exercise for the reader
        string word = args[0];
        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} has {1} possibilities",
                          word, Math.Pow(2, word.Length - 1));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Note that this assumes that the original word (with no dots) still counts. If you don't want it to count, subtract one from the result.

EDIT: I've changed the computation to use `Math.Pow` so that:

- It copes with words with more than 33 letters (up to another limit, of course)
- It's clearer

Comment: @Paul: Why? The question doesn't state that you *have* to add any dots, as far as I can tell. Will edit to make it clearer though.

Comment: The question title does (it implies you have to add dots)

Comment: can you explain what is happening in this line '1 << (word.Length - 1)'

Comment: It's Power(2,word.Length-1) but on `int`'s using a bitshift.

Answer (score 2):

Number of combinations:

```
string s = "abcd";
int len = s.Length;
int combinations = 1 << (len - 1);
```

*EDIT*: as Paul notes in the comments,

```
int combinations = 1 << (len - 1) - 1;
```

to remove the word that contains no dots if that's not a valid combination.

Comment: I think you mean `1 << (len - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a program?

if the string is length n, then there are n-1 places you can put a .

In any place, there can either be a . or not, that is, two options.

SO the answer is 2**(n-1) - 1 (the -1 being for the answer that has no dots, i.e the original word)